# ISampleGrabberCB::Sample not working

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, directshow, directshow.net

I am trying to convert every frame I get from my sample grabber into a bitmap however it does not seem to work.

I am using the `SampleCB` as follows:

```
int ISampleGrabberCB.SampleCB(double SampleTime, IMediaSample sample)
    {
        try
        {
            int lengthOfFrame = sample.GetActualDataLength();
            IntPtr buffer;
            if (sample.GetPointer(out buffer) == 0 && lengthOfFrame > 0)
            {
                Bitmap bitmapOfFrame = new Bitmap(width, height, capturePitch, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, buffer);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapOfFrame);
                Pen framePen = new Pen(Color.Black);
                g.DrawLine(framePen, 30, 30, 50, 50);
                g.Flush();
            }
        CopyMemory(imageBuffer, buffer, lengthOfFrame);           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sample);


        return 0;
    }
```

I am drawing a small graphic on it as a tester and it does not seem to work. From what I believe this should be adding a small line to each frame therefore updating my preview with the line.

I can give additional code if needed (e.g How i set up my graph and connect my ISampleGrabber)

Edited with what i think Dee Mon means:

```
int ISampleGrabberCB.SampleCB(double SampleTime, IMediaSample sample)
{
    try
    {        

        int lengthOfFrame = sample.GetActualDataLength();
        IntPtr buffer;
        BitmapData bitmapData = new BitmapData();
        if (sample.GetPointer(out buffer) == 0 && lengthOfFrame > 0)
        {                    
            Bitmap bitmapOfFrame = new Bitmap(width, height, capturePitch, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, buffer);                    
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapOfFrame);
            Pen framePen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            g.DrawLine(framePen, 30, 30, 50, 50);
            g.Flush();
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmapOfFrame.Width, bitmapOfFrame.Height);
            bitmapData = bitmapOfFrame.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            IntPtr bitmapPointer = bitmapData.Scan0;


            CopyMemory(bitmapPointer, buffer, lengthOfFrame); 
            BitmapOfFrame.UnlockData(bitmapData);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sample);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a Bitmap it copies data to its own internal buffer and all the drawing goes in that buffer, not in yours. Use Bitmap.LockBits and BitmapData class to get its contents after you draw your stuff in the bitmap.

Comment: I have added my interpretation of what you meant in the original post. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Well, you've got bitmapData but then you don't use it. At least in this snippet. Do you want the updated picture be saved in a bmp file or just passed down the stream to a renderer?

Comment: Basically I want to process every new frame. I would like to do this using a bitmap as a bitmap is needed by an external library which will process each image, I would also like to draw a crosshair to each frame so I think adding graphics to a bitmap will be easier than other methods.

Comment: I have changed the OP with what I think I should be doing with the bitmap data to achieve the above result is this right?

Comment: You're getting closer. But I think you've got parameters to CopyMemory wrong. The first one should be destination, the second one source.

Comment: What would be my destination if I want to pass them to the live preview? As I wish to edit the frame before it is shown?

Comment: In your case "buffer" points to the sample content, so it should be the destination.

Comment: I have now fixed it thank you, i used the link you gave me from the other question: http://www.infognition.com/blog/2013/working_with_raw_video_in_c_sharp_directshow.html Thanks for your help! :)